# can't-configure-ngx-ui-loader in angular

Tags: angular, ngx-ui-loader

I don't why the ngx-ui-loader is not working. I followed the installation guide on  https://tdev.app/ngx-ui-loader

My appModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NgxUiLoaderModule,
  NgxUiLoaderConfig,
  NgxUiLoaderHttpModule,
  SPINNER,
  POSITION,
  PB_DIRECTION } from 'ngx-ui-loader';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// modulos
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
// import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
// import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';

import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { AngularMaterialModule } from './shared/angular-material.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';


//components

// serviços
import { LoaderService } from './components/loader/loader.service';
import { RequestInterceptor } from './core/auth/request.interceptor';


///em teste
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { filterReducer, integrationsReducer } from './reducers';
//import { reducers, metaReducers } from './reducers';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

import { NgxMaterialTimepickerModule } from 'ngx-material-timepicker';
import { filterLogReducer } from './reducers/filter-logs.reducer';
import { instanceLoginReducer } from './reducers/instance-login.reducer';


const ngxUiLoaderConfig: NgxUiLoaderConfig = {
  fgsColor: 'red',
  fgsPosition: POSITION.bottomCenter,
  fgsSize: 40,
  // fgsType: SPINNER.rectangleBounce, // background spinner type
  fgsType: SPINNER.chasingDots, // foreground spinner type
  pbDirection: PB_DIRECTION.leftToRight, // progress bar direction
  pbThickness: 5 // progress bar thickness
};

registerLocaleData(localePt, 'pt-BR');

export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularMaterialModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgbModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      filterLogs: filterLogReducer,
      filter: filterReducer,
      integrations: integrationsReducer,
      instanceLogin: instanceLoginReducer
    }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 5, logOnly: environment.production }),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    NgxMaterialTimepickerModule.setLocale('pt-BR') ,
    NgxUiLoaderModule.forRoot(ngxUiLoaderConfig),
    NgxUiLoaderHttpModule
  ],
  exports: [

  ],
  providers: [
    CookieService,
    LoaderService,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: RequestInterceptor, multi: true },
    //{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'pt-BR' },
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt-BR' },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my appComponent.html

```
<ngx-ui-loader></ngx-ui-loader>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The component where I'm trying to use it

```
constructor(
        private messageLogService: MessageLogService
        private ngxService: NgxUiLoaderService
    ){}


searchMessageLog(filterMessageLog?: SearchFilterMessageLog, page?) {
        debugger
        this.ngxService.start();
        this.messageLogService.getMessageLogDetails(filterMessageLog, page)
            .subscribe(
                (data: HttpResponse<any>) => {
                    this.messageLogs = this.getMessageLogConfiguredForTable(data.body['result'])
                    this.pagination = this.newPaginationService.configurePagination(data.body)
                },
                this.utilsService.showAlertRequestError
            ).add(()=>{
                this.ngxService.stop()
            })
    }
```

I tried to do what is on the post below, no success although

[Can't configure ngx-ui-loader from app.module.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54920614/cant-configure-ngx-ui-loader-from-app-module-ts-file?answertab=active#tab-top)

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I thought it coud be a version problem because my local version is 8.3.0 and I've installed ngx-ui-loader 9.x.x so, I removed ngx-ui-loader and installed ngx-ui-loader 8.0.0.

No success.

Comment: Apparently ngx-ui-loader has compatibility issues with angular ivy rendering. I can confirm this issue with angular 9.1.6.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give id to the loader, by-default the id is master so in config:

```
const ngxUiLoaderConfig: NgxUiLoaderConfig = {
              fgsColor: 'red',
              fgsPosition: POSITION.bottomCenter,
              fgsSize: 40,
              // fgsType: SPINNER.rectangleBounce, // background spinner type
              fgsType: SPINNER.chasingDots, // foreground spinner type
              pbDirection: PB_DIRECTION.leftToRight, // progress bar direction
              pbThickness: 5 // progress bar thickness
              masterLoaderId: "master", //by-default its master
            };
```

Also when you are calling the loader through service, pass the id in function like this:

```
      this.ngxService.startLoader('master');
```

Similarly for stopping the loader:

```
      this.ngxService.stopLoader('master');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged here because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what the code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful for other users also as well as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

By default, NgxUiLoaderHttpModule will show background loader.

If you need to show foreground spinner, Add `NgxUiLoaderHttpModule.forRoot({ showForeground: true })` in imports array of app.module :

```
import { NgxUiLoaderModule,
NgxUiLoaderConfig,
NgxUiLoaderHttpModule,
SPINNER,
POSITION,
PB_DIRECTION } from 'ngx-ui-loader';

const ngxUiLoaderConfig: NgxUiLoaderConfig = {
  fgsColor: 'red',
  fgsPosition: POSITION.bottomCenter,
  fgsSize: 40,
  fgsType: SPINNER.chasingDots, 
  pbDirection: PB_DIRECTION.leftToRight, 
  pbThickness: 5 
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    ..
     NgxUiLoaderModule.forRoot(ngxUiLoaderConfig), 
    NgxUiLoaderHttpModule.forRoot({ showForeground: true })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, instead of

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    NgbModule,
    ParticlesModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgxUiLoaderModule,
    NgxUiLoaderHttpModule.forRoot({ showForeground: true })
  ],
```

in your imports array in app.module.ts , use

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    NgbModule,
    ParticlesModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgxUiLoaderModule.forRoot({  "bgsColor": "red",
    "bgsOpacity": 0.5,
    "bgsPosition": "bottom-right",
    "bgsSize": 60,
    "bgsType": "ball-spin-clockwise",
    "blur": 5,
    "delay": 0,
    "fastFadeOut": true,
    "fgsColor": "#ffffff",
    "fgsPosition": "center-center",
    "fgsSize": 60,
    "fgsType": "three-strings",
    "gap": 24,
    "logoPosition": "center-center",
    "logoSize": 120,
    "logoUrl": "",
    "masterLoaderId": "master",
    "overlayBorderRadius": "0",
    "overlayColor": "rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.8)",
    "pbColor": "red",
    "pbDirection": "ltr",
    "pbThickness": 3,
    "hasProgressBar": false,
    "text": "Loading...",
    "textColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "textPosition": "center-center",
    "maxTime": -1,
    "minTime": 300}),
    NgxUiLoaderHttpModule.forRoot({ showForeground: true })
  ],
```

restart ng serve

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
**in your app.module.ts:**

//#1.- Import the modules necessary of ngx-ui-loader

import {
  NgxUiLoaderModule, NgxUiLoaderConfig, SPINNER, POSITION, PB_DIRECTION, 
  NgxUiLoaderRouterModule, NgxUiLoaderHttpModule, NgxUiLoaderHttpConfig
} from 'ngx-ui-loader';

//#2.- Create a const with the configuration of ngx-ui-loader that you need 
const ngxUiLoaderConfig: NgxUiLoaderConfig = {
  bgsColor: "#1b1a5c",
  bgsOpacity: 0.5,
  bgsPosition: "top-right",
  bgsSize: 60,
  bgsType: "double-bounce",
  blur: 5,
  delay: 0,
  fastFadeOut: true,
  fgsColor: "red",
  fgsPosition: "center-center",
  fgsSize: 60,
  fgsType: "square-jelly-box",
  gap: 24,
  logoPosition: "center-center",
  logoSize: 120,
  logoUrl: "",
  masterLoaderId: "master",
  overlayBorderRadius: "0",
  overlayColor: "rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.8)",
  pbColor: "#2e41d6",
  pbDirection: "ltr",
  pbThickness: 3,
  hasProgressBar: true,
  text: "Cargando",
  textColor: "#FFFFFF",
  textPosition:"center-center",
  maxTime: -1,
  minTime: 1000
};

//#3 Create a const with the configuration of http requests 
const ngxUiLoaderHttpConfig: NgxUiLoaderHttpConfig = {
    showForeground: true, //For showing loader automatically when the app get a request from the server
    exclude: [   //allows to exclude requests included in this section
      "www.test/qq/general/getOneGlobal/expediente/obtieneUnExpediente",
      "www.test/qq/usuario/obtenUnUsuario"
    ],
}


@NgModule({
    
declarations: [],
    
        
   //#4.- In imports area set the const **ngxUiLoaderConfig** and **ngxUiLoaderHttpConfig** configuration
    imports: [ NgxUiLoaderModule.forRoot(ngxUiLoaderConfig),
               NgxUiLoaderRouterModule, // import this module for showing loader automatically when navigating between app routes
               NgxUiLoaderHttpModule.forRoot(ngxUiLoaderHttpConfig),
                  ],
        
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [StartComponent],
      entryComponents: []
    })
```